# How to permanently change a system property in TeamCity 6 from a build step

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-6

I have found a way to change a property in TeamCity:

```
##teamcity[setParameter name='ddd' value='fff']
```

But unfortunately this change only occurs for the current build. I want this change to be PERMANENT, but TeamCity only changes this for the current running build.

How do I make a permanent change to a system property in TeamCity?

Comment: I usually edit the configuration files. Which property are you trying to set?

Comment: Its a custom system property. Im trying that route now. Python script that edits the config file.

Comment: In TeamCity 7.0 you can change build configuration parameters using REST API, see http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings.

Comment: I am aware of that. Sadly we can't upgrade at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution using TeamCity 6.5 was to edit the Xml configuration file programmatically using a python script.

A build step calls the python script to change the variable during each build.

Answer (score 0):

Use the REST API which is a feature of TeamCity 7.0

Api details here - http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings

I use this method to get and set properties from powershell during a build.

Comment: Thank you. I am fully aware of this feature but I was limited to version 6.5 when I had this problem, so the API is not relevant. I specified the version of TC in the question.

Comment: You did but I was also not aware/sure that 6.5 was a hard restriction. The API is also very easy to use and I'd encourage the upgrade.

Comment: The problem with this solution is authentication. I need my build agents to be able to change one parameter in the build, but I don't want to deploy credentials to them, and I don't think the user management is granular enough anyway to let me specify that they should only be able to change that one parameter.