# How can I make TeamCity build parameters dynamic?

Tags: java, version-control, teamcity

My situation is:

- I have some revisions of code (in SVN)
- I have some build configurations for different applications
- I have a Map in another app (Zookeeper) which knows what revisions I want to build now

I want TeamCity to update build parameters dynamically when build process starts.
Any ideas?

Comment: The later versions have REST API, I would think you can just kick off a build and pass the params you want.  http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin

Comment: I was looking for something equivalent to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin and came across this question.

Answer (score 2):

I have found answer in similar question [How to permanently change a system property in TeamCity 6 from a build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789030/how-to-permanently-change-a-system-property-in-teamcity-6-5-from-a-build-step)

Here is the recipe:
[Adding or Changing a Build Parameter from a Build Step](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameterfromaBuildStep)